# laravel routes , how to redirect if statement , routes.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i have in routes.php user and admin routes , how to can access admin routes just if `Session::get('admin')==1` ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Q25o.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [define a middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware#defining-middleware), for example:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
class CheckAge
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!session()->has('admin') || session('admin') != 1) {
            return redirect('/');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

[Register it](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware#registering-middleware) and [apply it to routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes) you want to protect.

Comment: and how to apply to routes?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like you have a specific problems in terms of code, so I'm just going to point you to the documentation on Middleware.

Middleware get's executed before it reaches the controller, therefore you can apply your logic there, simply create a new middleware, add an if statement but instead of returning `$next` return `response()` with your appropriate response should the middleware fail.

[Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware)